# Which variogram method for ordinary kriging?

Tags: climate-change, mapping, isotopic, interpolation

I want to plot atmospheric data (<sup>2</sup>H and <sup>18</sup>O) on a map and use ordinary kriging for the interpolation. Now I have the question how to quantify which variogram method (Gaussian, exponential spherical) I should use. Is there a mathematical approach to quantify each method or should I just plot my data in the variogram and see which method covers the most points?

Comment: It's been a very, very long time since I've done any variography. Things may have changed since then, but then I plotted the variogram first to see what I'd get.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try my best using the visual way ;)